# Clarity to MVC in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

please it is okay for me to use UIProgressView as a parameter in function inside model class. I want to keep my project 100% MVC design pattern

Example

```
func downloading(mediaUrl: String, downloadProgress: UIProgressView) {
Alamofire.download(mediaUrl, to: destination).responseData { (resp) in
        if let mediaData = resp.value {
            //get the data and now something with it
            print(mediaData)
        }
}.downloadProgress { (progress) in
           downloadProgress.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
}
```

in my model class.

Comment: Your model objects shouldn't know or be dependent of any UI objects, the controller (C) handles the communication between the UI (V) and the model (M) objects. _Edit None of that code should be in a model object_

Comment: May I suggest you read up on MVC so you properly understand the basics, there are plenty of articles online both more general and for swift.

Comment: Check out Stanford's course on [iTunes U](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1309275316).  The second video is all about MVC.

Comment: FWIW, not only should a model class (the “M”) not be interacting with UI controls (the “V”), but if you’re really concerned about nice architecture with separation of responsibilities, I wouldn’t personally recommend having the model interacting directly with the networking library...

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't , you need to create a function like

```
func setValue(_ res:Float) {
  self.progressView.progress = res
}
```

inside your vc and call it from your controller that gets the value from your response